# Setting a UIView's height based on UIScrollView's height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have 5 `UIViews` that are contained within a `UIScrollView`. Then I set the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize.height` to 10,000.

How do I change each view's height that is contained within the `UIScrollView` to be `1/5` of the `contentSize.height`? Also, I wanted to mention that the views and the scroll view are all created through Interface Builder. Here is some of the code in the View Controller I have tried:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    scrollView.contentSize.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    scrollView.contentSize.height = 10000
    myView.bounds.size.height = scrollView.contentSize.height * 1/5
    print(scrollView.contentSize.height)
}
```

This code will work, and set the `myView` height to 2000, but the very second I scroll, the view snaps back to its original height that I set in Interface Builder. Also I wanted to add that when I print the scrollView's `contentSize` it returns `10,000` like expected.

So long story short: **How do I make a UIView's height 1/5 of the Scroll Views content size?**

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @beyowulf Yes, I am using auto layout, but I am willing to disable it if I have to.

Comment: When using auto layout you should update constraints not set frames/bounds. You can set myView's height to be 1/5 of your scrollView's contentView by selecting both, adding an equal height constraint then selecting that constraint and change multiplier from 1 to 0.20 in the inspector.

Comment: @beyowulf Will it work if I set create a constraint in IB where I set the myView to have an Equal Height Constraint with a multiplier of 1:5 and then call update constraints in the code?

Comment: @beyowulf It didn't, I will try to create a constraint to the contentSize instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add constraints on the contentSize like `V:|[view1(==view2)][view2(==view3)]...[view5(==view1)]|` and this way views will pinned to each other and from the top to the bottom of the content size and each will have equal height.

Comment: Yes, that is also another solution to this issue. This probably result in better code because there are less `@IBOutlets` involved so I am going to mark your solution as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I found a solution. Following **@beyowulf** advice, what I did was I created a height constraint for each of the five views in the `UIScrollView`. Then what I did was I created an `@IBOutlet` for each of the height constraints. Finally, in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method I modified the height constraints `constant` property to 1/5 of the height of the `UIScrollView` content size.

So, here is some example code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.pointBreakdownScrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    pointBreakdownScrollView.contentSize.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    scrollView.contentSize.height = 2000

    view1HeightConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentSize.height * 1/5
    view2HeightConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentSize.height * 1/5
    view3HeightConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentSize.height * 1/5
    view4HeightConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentSize.height * 1/5
    view5HeightConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentSize.height * 1/5
}
```